# Adding/Removing event listener

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-listener

Sorry if the question is stupid. But I wanted to refactor my code a bit and got some suggestions, but can't really solve this one problem. I have a div in html that contains 9 buttons. Like this:

```
 <div class="board" id="board">
            <button class="button" id="0"></button>
            <button class="button" id="1"></button>
            <button class="button" id="2"></button>
            <button class="button" id="3"></button>
            <button class="button" id="4"></button>
            <button class="button" id="5"></button>
            <button class="button" id="6"></button>
            <button class="button" id="7"></button>
            <button class="button" id="8"></button>          
    </div>
```

I am wondering if it is possible to add event listener to the whole container and then remove it for each button individually. The main point of this is so that button would be clicked only once. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
const buttonsContainer = document.querySelector('.board');

buttonsContainer.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(event){
    const button = event.target;
    console.log(button.id + " was clicked"); 
    button.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);  
}
```

I looked for solutions and only thing I found was to setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        button.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }, 0);
```

Didn't get this, and it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Not possible as the event is bound to the container - not the buttons.  If you don't want your buttons to fire the container event, then use [`e.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: Why do you need to remove the event listener on button element?

Comment: The point is that each button should be clicked only once per game.

Answer (score 2):

it's possible to add a single event listener to the container element and then remove it for each button individually.

the second issue is that you're removing the event listener from the button inside the event handler function itself. This means that the event listener is only removed after the first click on the button, but not for subsequent clicks.

One way to solve this is to remove the event listener from the container element instead of the button, and then check if the clicked element is a button using the event

try this:

```
const buttonsContainer = document.querySelector('.board');

buttonsContainer.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(event) {
    const button = event.target;
    if (button.matches('.button')) {
        console.log(button.id + " was clicked");
        buttonsContainer.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response! Well, I tried this but the problem is that it removes event listener from the whole container and other buttons don't react after one click. What I need is to remove event listener from the only button that was clicked, so that buttons would be clicked only once per game

Comment: try to add the "once" option to the event listener
buttonsContainer.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {once: true});